# Transferring emails from an old Gmail account to a new one

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, email

I use a domain email address as xyz@abc.net (GMail based).
I have also purchased a new domain and want my new email address to be xyz@abc.in ( also GMail based) without losing any email from the abc.net domain.

Can someone help with this please?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: And why would downloading all the emails and moving from one account to another not work?